# How to develop a jabber client

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, xmpp

I am using the asmack library in Android to develop a Jabber client which enables users to chat between themselves by connecting to the xmpp server. I want to achieve the same in iPhone too which connects to the server and chatting can be done among users.

I want to know if there are any libraries like asmack for iPhone which enables me to connect to the server and i can perform chatting among the users.

Please suggest if there are any other alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find a list of XMPP libraries at the [XSF site](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).  In particular, the C libraries or the Objective-C one might be a good fit.

Comment: Using the same "xmppframework" (xsf site). I'm able to logged-in but not able to get buddy list. Shows the error ( 400) bad-request.

Comment: Start another question, posting a small example of what you have tried, and detailing how it fails.  400 probably means you're not as logged in as you think you are.